# Pass array of objects from angular to laravel

Tags: ajax, angularjs, laravel

I have an array of objects,

I have angular in client side, laravel in the server side.

i should use $http.post and with it i need to pass the data, is it passed as a json object by default?

Or should i use some kind of parser...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! Use the $http data-object.

Example here:

```
$http({method: 'POST', url: '/api/function/'+$scope.object.id, data: data }).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
        });
```